# Problems installing WAS8.5 support in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, websphere

I am trying to upgrade my environment from Juno to Kepler. However, when I try to install the IBM plugins found here..

```
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/V8.5/
```

It won't let them install because it says I am missing some plugins, anyone know where I can find them?

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: WebSphere® Application Server V8.5 Tools 8.5.1001.v20121206_1718 (com.ibm.websphere.wdt.st.v85.feature.group 8.5.1001.v20121206_1718)
>     Missing requirement: IBM Enterprise Navigator Component 7.5.101.v20120918_0238 (com.ibm.etools.project.explorer 7.5.101.v20120918_0238) requires 'bundle com.ibm.icu [3.6.1,4.5.0)' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Enterprise Explorer 1.0.1.v20120918_0238 (com.ibm.etools.project.explorer.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.v20120918_0238)
>       To: com.ibm.etools.project.explorer [7.5.101.v20120918_0238]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Java EE Development Tools 1.0.0.v20121205_0320 (com.ibm.wdt.javaee.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v20121205_0320)
>       To: com.ibm.etools.project.explorer.feature.feature.group 1.0.1
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Shared Server Tools 1.0.100.v20121205_0320 (com.ibm.websphere.wdt.st.common.feature.group 1.0.100.v20121205_0320)
>       To: com.ibm.wdt.javaee.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: WebSphere® Application Server V8.5 Tools 8.5.1001.v20121206_1718 (com.ibm.websphere.wdt.st.v85.feature.group 8.5.1001.v20121206_1718)
>       To: com.ibm.websphere.wdt.st.common.feature.group 1.0.100

UPDATE: Could it be that this isn't supported for Kepler yet?!?!?!
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14694723

Comment: You got your answer, doesn't support kepler, it takes IBM time to support new versions of eclipse.

Comment: Apparently.... I guess moving such a big machine is difficult. They don't even have a beta?

Comment: It seems the beta ([v.Next](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/wasdev/entry/download?lang=en)) doesn't support kepler as well

Comment: BETA was released before Kepler and that's why the tools may lag behind.

Comment: Kepler isn't even released yet. Why would you expect IBM to support it?

Comment: It is released what are you talking about... http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php?osType=win32

Comment: @Jackie Isaac means that Kepler's version is RC3 (Release Candidate 3).

Comment: As of Oct 25, 2013, Kepler is now supported by WDT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric Peters announced in a Blog-post last Friday, that WebSphere Developer Tools V8.5.5.1 are available for Eclipse Kepler SR1 (4.3.1), and for Juno (4.2.2):
https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/2013/10/25/websphere-developer-tools-v8-5-5-1-eclipse-kepler/

Answer (score 4):

Kepler is released and you can vote for the RFE at IBM to add websphere plugin support for Kepler.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=36925

The RFE is linked from the websphere developer forum:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0b0dff76-f833-4607-95e8-538a9ddaec75

Answer (score 1):

Apparently IBM doesn't support Eclipse Kepler yet :-(